# malformedXML: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jsf

I use JSF 2.0 and Twitter Bootstrap.

I am trying to change a value in field after an ajax request. However, I get a malformedXML error when I change value and inputText lost focus. The xhtml file looks like :

```
<h:inputText value="#{product.count}>
    <f:ajax listener="#{orderBean.changeTotal} render="outputTotal" />
    <f:attribute name="productId" value="#{product.id}" />
</h:inputText>

.....

<h:outputText id="outputTotal" value="#{product.total}" />

.....
```

And the OrderBean have a code:

```
public void changeTotal(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

    Integer id = (Integer) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("productId");
        for (FoProduct pio : fo_orderList) {

            if (pio.getId() == id) {

                pio.setTotal(pio.getCount() * pio.getPrice());

            }

        }
}
```

Result: total value is changed, and JSF show me message "mallformedXML: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount"

P.S.: More xhtml for Hector William:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{orderBean.fo_orderList}" var="product">
<h:form>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Count:
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <h:inputText class="input-sm" value="#{product.count}" >
                      <f:ajax listener="#{orderBean.changeTotal}" render="outputTotal"/>
                        <f:attribute name="productId" value="#{product.id}" />
                    </h:inputText>
                </div>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:outputLabel value="Price:" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <h:outputText value="#{product.price}" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <h:outputLabel value="Total:" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <h:outputText id="outputTotal" value="#{product.total}" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: I'm sorry could you show me more of the html, or at least if the components above are in the same level of the tree?

Comment: The oficial tutorial (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_ajax.htm) gets error too.

Comment: I ran the example an it worked for me ...

Comment: I wanted to suggest you to change the *render="outputTotal"* by *render=":outputTotal"* ...


But I don't think is a problem with the render, I think is a problem  with the sended value...


Can you confirm that you're receiving the same value you're writing in the input?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a double quote on the f:ajax tag.  Is this an accident in your code sample because that could be the problem.

Comment: Yes, I've receiving the same value I writining in the input.

Comment: Tag <f:ajax> always give me this error. If I try to use ajax for any task, I give malformXML in Firefox.
In Rekonq I give "malformXML: IndexSizeException. DOM Error 1"

Comment: Maybe wrong configs? pom.xml, faces-config.xml...

Comment: If I create new web project and add example code than it's work. Please, help me. I don't understand this trouble...

Comment: @Vikom the only thing that gave me problems when I adapted your code to the example, was when you try to retrieve the attribute. It gave me an error ,but not the one you're mention... At this point with this little information is really hard to tell whats going on...

Comment: I will try to remake my project today. Maybe the problem is in configs (I experimented a lot with IceFaces in my project).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I create Java WebProject - it's working.
If I create Java Maven WebProject - malformedXML...